# How to put out array

Tags: php, arrays, echo

How can I put out the following array?

```
$newdata =  array (
    'Spiel_ID' => $ausgabeT->Spielplan_ID,
    'Heimmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinT->Name,
    'Gastmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinTGast->Name
);

var_dump($newdata);
foreach($newdata as $result) {
    echo $result['Spiel_ID'], '<br>';
}
```

For the `echo` I get error:

> Illegal string offset 'Spiel_ID'

Comment: `echo $result, '<br>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `echo` a value that doesn't exist.

When you use `foreach ($newdata as $result)` the $result is a `string`, not an `array`.

You have two options, based on this structure:

```
$newdata = array (
    'Spiel_ID' => $ausgabeT->Spielplan_ID,
    'Heimmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinT->Name,
    'Gastmannschaft' => $ausgabeVereinTGast->Name
);
```

#### Option 1 — Display all values

```
foreach($newdata as $result) {
    echo $result;
}
```

#### Option 2 — Display a single value

```
echo $newdata['Spiel_ID'];
```

#### Option 3 — Display Key + Value

```
foreach($newdata as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I want output only for example Spiel_ID or Heimmannschaft. Is it not possible with this structure? What I have to change to get this?

Comment: You can just use Option 2 in my answer to achieve that. Just echo `$array['key]` based on what you want to see. For example, `echo $newdata['Spiel_ID']` or `echo $newdata['Heimmannschaft']`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just `echo $result`